# Functions satisfying Mean Value Theorem in a special way

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ be the set of all functions $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ that satify the following two properties:

1. $f$ has derivatives of all orders, and
2. for all $x,y \in \mathbb R$, $f(x+y)-f(y-x)=2xf'(y)$

Show that any $f \in A$ is a polynomial of degree $\le 2$.

One proof is very easy. Any polynomial of degree $\le 2$ belongs to $A$ is easy to prove. Please help me with the proof of the converse : No other functions belong to $A$.

Comment: differentiate twice in $x$ so calling $f''=g$ one gets $g(x+y)-g(y-x)=0$; letting $y=x$ gives$g(2x)=g(0)$ hence $g$ constant etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x+y)-f(y-x)=2xf'(y)$$

Derivating two times w.r.t. $x$, you get
$$f''(x+y)-f''(y-x)=0$$
For $x=y$, you get $f''(2x)-f''(0)=0$. So $f''$ is constant, so $f'$ is polynomial of degree $1$, so $f$ is polynomial of degree $2$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint 1**:

If $f$ is a function with vanishing third derivative, it is a polynomial of degree $\le 2$

**Hint 2**:

Differentiate $f$ three times and choose a suitable $x$